# Virtual listview doesn't get CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT c++

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I am trying to change the color of listview item based on what I type on text box. When user type some text based on some logic I use I have below code

    ListView_SetItemState(hList, wordid,    LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED);

Then on my WM_NOTIFY block I have this;

```cpp
case WM_NOTIFY:
{

    NMHDR *pNMHDR= (NMHDR*)lParam;

    switch(pNMHDR->code){
           case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
                OnGetdispinfo(pNMHDR);
                break;
            case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
               wmnot= OnDraw(pNMHDR);
               return wmnot;
                break;
         }

    return 0;

}
```

OnGetdispinfo function fills my virtual listview by using Sqlite. In my ondraw function I have this

```cpp
int OnDraw (NMHDR* pNMHDR){
    int nIndex,state;
    int result;
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR ); 

if (pLVCD->nmcd.hdr.hwndFrom==hList)
{
    switch (pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        result= CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        break;
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        result=CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        break;
    case CDDS_SUBITEM|CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        nIndex=pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
        state=ListView_GetItemState(hList,nIndex,LVIF_TEXT |LVIF_PARAM);
        if(state&LVIS_SELECTED==LVIS_SELECTED)   
        {
            pLVCD->clrTextBk=RGB(124,34,78);
            return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }
        result= CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        break;
    default:
        result=CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        break;
    }
}
    return result;  // CDRF_DODEFAULT



}
```

I get CDDS_PREPAINT message but I don't get CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT message at all.

My Listview has this styles according to Spy++

## Windows Styles (5021580D)

WS_CHILDWINDOW
WS_VISIBLE
WS_VSCROLL
WS_TABSTOP
LVS_REPORT
LVS_SINGLESEL
LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS

## Extended Styles (00000204)

WS_EX_LEFT
WS_EX_LTRREADING
WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR
WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY
WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Here is the fixed code.
First of all I added onchange notifier function so that I can detect changes for selection.

```cpp
void OnItemChange (LPARAM lParam)
{

    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMListView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(lParam);

    if ((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) 
        && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED))
    {

        ListView_RedrawItems(hList,Query.WordID,pNMListView->iItem);
        ListView_RedrawItems(hList,pNMListView->iItem,Query.WordID);
        Query.WordID=pNMListView->iItem;
        //DO STUFF;

    }


}
```

Then I modified my custom draw function as well.

```cpp
LRESULT OnDraw  (LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
    int nIndex;
    int state;
    if (lplvcd->nmcd.hdr.hwndFrom!=hList)
        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    switch(lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT : //Before the paint cycle begins
        return  CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: 
        return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;

    case CDDS_POSTPAINT:
        nIndex=lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
        state=lplvcd->nmcd.uItemState;
        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        nIndex=lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
        state=lplvcd->nmcd.uItemState;
        if  (  nIndex==Query.WordID)    {
        lplvcd->clrText   =  GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);
        lplvcd->clrTextBk = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
        return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }
        else{

            lplvcd->clrText   = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT);  
            lplvcd->clrTextBk = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW); 
            return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }
    default:
        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    }
    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
}
```

So basically, I am not selecting items by ListView Messages. Instead i set Query.WordID to the item I want to select and if the item is selected(either by mouse or programmatically) I manually change the color of the item.

Answer (score 2):

If your control is in a dialog, you have to return your result code using:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, result);
```

and then return `TRUE` from the `DlgProc` itself.

Comment: Thanks. I have also found that but again I can't change the the color of selected item. I want to achieve something like this. User will write something and corresponding item will be selected and highlighted from the list view. I can easily do if I send focus to list view but then user has to click to edit box to enter the string again. So what I should do to change the color of list view item same as selected item in default list view without losing focus of edit control. Thanks.